# Checking if something is in the way or not in a 3d environment while also snapping to a different object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have written some code that snaps a cylinder to an existing cylinder using a for loop on a gameobject list I call cylinders. Below is the code I use for "snapping" the cylinder to another cylinder using the mouse position and a "translucentPrefab". I would like to know if there is another object obstructing the placement. For performance reasons I would like to avoid using another for loop through my list to check each position. Is there any good solution for this. Could I use a "fake" 2d array since I mostly use full integer boxes and set squares to occupied in that array. Or is there a smarter approach?

```
                `if (worldMousePosition.x > centerPoint.x && Vector3.Distance(worldMousePosition, centerPoint) < snappingRange)
                {
             
                    translucentPrefab.transform.position = rightPosition;
                    snapped = true;
                    left = false;
                    if (renderer != null)
                    {
                        // Set the prefab material to translucent and green
                        material.color = new Color(0, 1, 1, 0.5f);
                    }
                }`
```

I have tried using box colliders in many ways to check in the same space as the new cylinder, however all attempts have been a faliure.

Comment: There are many ways, for example an `OverlapSphere`. See many other ways in the Physics class: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.html

Comment: Thank you @Absinthe I used this but with a OverlapBox. This way I could keep only one collider on each item and counted if I struck more than one since I am always connected to one edge when the item is snapped in place.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Physics.SphereCastAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCastAll.html) at point where you cursor is and just iterate over all object that `SphereCastAll` returns.

And if you don't want objects to count toward physics you can add special physic layer for just this. And that adjust collision matrix.